# Can't embed variable in mail function php

Tags: php, email

I want to send email with different subjects. I have the following code that get mail subject and message from the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT mail_subject, mail_content FROM new_business WHERE business_name = '$biz_name'";

$query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $subject = $row['mail_subject']; //Getting mail subject to send
        $mail_content = $row['mail_content']; //Getting mail content 
                    }
echo $subject; //checking if it gets subject and it surely does.
$to = 'utopian51@gmail.com';

mail($to, $subject, $mail_content);//Mail is not sent
```

If subject pulls data from database mail is not sent. I have checked several times including spam and also checked if subject gets any data from database before embedding it in mail function. It seems it gets the right data but **the mail is not sent.**

But when i hardcode the subject like this: `$subject = 'this is a test subject';` , **the mail is sent successfully**. Why mail function does not let me embed variable that gets subject from database? I need to send the mails with different subject from database. Whats the solution?

Comment: Are you sure that `$subject` (when not hardcoded rather pulled from the DB) is a valid encoded string?

Comment: Check if you are getting data from database properly.

Comment: Try and replace `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))` with `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC))` and also as @b0s3 stated missing of `'` in his answer could be the reason also

Comment: @OfirBaruch yest it is and i get data from database successfully

Comment: @UtkarshVishnoi , I checked it but still no success

Comment: @SaifullahAlam The problem might be with gmail as you are not including any reference from where the mail is being sent. I recommend you to include additional headers referencing the sender's mail and character encoding. So that it may not be blacklisted or treated as spam.

Comment: Yeah that might be. I will add headers as fourth argument as embed the sender and see. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many things which are confusing about the code you've written. You never check for error conditions in the mysqli_ calls nor the mail() call. You run a query which will discard all but the last row (if any). However the way to diagnose issues with mail() is not to watch your inbox. In more than 99% of cases the problem is with the interface between PHP and the MTA or with the MTA configuration itself.

You have provided no details of either.

I would recommend you use simply:

```
mail('utopian51@gmail.com', 'test', date('r'));
```

and start debugging your MTA.

Independently you can work on your bulk emailing script, simply writing to a file instead of calling mail() until both parts are working.